# Passing input$ value to JS() statement in shiny data table

Tags: r, shiny, dt

Using this code to format the rows in my datatable

```
 rowCallback = DT::JS(
      'function(row, data) {
        // Bold cells for those >= 5 in the first column
        if (parseFloat(data[0]) >= 5.0)
          $("td", row).css("background", "red");
      }'
    )
```

I would like to alter this code so that rather than the static "5.0" value, highlighting is based on an an input$ value. So that users could click on a point on the chart, and rows with that value would be highlighted in the data table.

But substituting input$click for 5 doesn't seem to work. Thoughts?

```
rowCallback = DT::JS(
          'function(row, data) {
            // Bold cells for those >= 5 in the first column
            if (parseFloat(data[0]) >= input$click)
              $("td", row).css("background", "red");
          }'
        )
```

Answer (score 3):

Using the newest version of DT, you can do this without any Javascript using `formatStyle`.

Here's an example:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
shinyApp(
        ui = fluidPage(numericInput("cutoff", "Test", 5, min = 0, max = 10, step = 1),
                       DT::dataTableOutput('tbl')
        ),
        server = function(input, output) {
                output$tbl = DT::renderDataTable(
                        datatable(iris, options = list(lengthChange = FALSE)) %>% formatStyle(
                                'Sepal.Length',
                                target = 'row',
                                backgroundColor = styleInterval(input$cutoff, c('gray', 'yellow'))
                        )
                )
        }
)
```

More info and examples [here](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/functions.html) and [here](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/010-style.html).

You will probably need to install the development version of DT by running:

```
devtools::install_github('rstudio/DT')
```

If you can't use the dev version of DT, here's another solution:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
shinyApp(
        ui = fluidPage(numericInput("cutoff", "Test", 5, min = 0, max = 10, step = 1),
                       uiOutput("tbl_holder")

        ),
        server = function(input, output) {
                output$tbl_holder <- renderUI({
                        DT::dataTableOutput('tbl')
                })

                output$tbl = DT::renderDataTable(
                        datatable(iris, options = list(lengthChange = FALSE,rowCallback = DT::JS(
                                paste0('function(row, data) {
                                // Bold cells for those >= 5 in the first column
                                if (parseFloat(data[0]) >=',input$cutoff,')
                                $("td", row).css("background", "red");
        }')
        )))) 
        }
)
```

You can use `paste` to add the cutoff in the JS function and `renderUi`/`uiOutput` so that the function that prints the datatable is updated each time the cutoff changes.

Comment: I've seen that feature but I can't access the devtools version of DT. It keeps telling me it can't connect to server. Then I tried downloading it directly and installing if from a local file, and it kept crashing R, causing memory issues, so I went back to the regular version of DT until they fix that. If it can't be done without using the dev version I'll have to add a second conditional table I guess, but it seems like a waste of space for a simple highlighting issue.

Comment: ok that's strange, I added another solution if you can't use the dev version.