# Pass shiny reactive() value into javascript part of DT

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, dt, flexdashboard

I want to pass a reactive value into the rowCallback in the **options** of the DT library. Please see example below. I am using this in a flexdashboard with shiny runtime.

Set up

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
    horizontal_layout: fill
runtime: shiny    
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(DT)
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
```

Column
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
````

Table with static value, *cutoff = 4* .Working.

````
### Chart A

```{r,eval=T}
output$mtcarsTable1 <- renderDataTable({
      DT::datatable(datasets::mtcars, 
      options = list( pageLength = 5,
                      searching= FALSE,
                      lengthChange = FALSE,
                      ordering=FALSE,
                      rowCallback = JS('
            function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull,cutoff=4) {
                                      // Bold and green cells for conditions
                                      if (parseFloat(aData[10]) >= cutoff)
                                      $("td:eq(4)", nRow).css("font-weight", "bold");
                                       }')))
    })
dataTableOutput('mtcarsTable1')

```
````

Table with reactive value, *cutoff = gearvalue()*, not working.

````
### Conditional Bold

```{r}
fillCol(flex = c(1, 6), 
      radioButtons("gearvalue","Sensitivity to gear column", c("4" = "4", "3" = "3"), inline=T),
    dataTableOutput('mtcarsTable2'),
     width = "100%")
```


```{r,eval=T}
output$mtcarsTable2 <- renderDataTable({
      DT::datatable(datasets::mtcars, 
      options = list( pageLength = 5,
                      searching= FALSE,
                      lengthChange = FALSE,
                      ordering=FALSE,
                      rowCallback = JS('
            function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull,cutoff=gearvalue()) {
                                      // Bold and green cells for conditions
                                      if (parseFloat(aData[10]) >= cutoff)
                                      $("td:eq(4)", nRow).css("font-weight", "bold");
                                       }')))
    })
```
````

Answer (score 1):

Got the the answer from here [Passing input$ value to JS() statement in shiny data table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35002057/passing-input-value-to-js-statement-in-shiny-data-table)

Need to set up line with input value in single quotes and works.

```
function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull, cutoff = ',input$gearvalue,')
```